# Ultrabeat contains no preset drumkits or samples

Tags: logic-pro

I am following this tutorial (

) on youtube and I encountered the problem that there are no presets delivered with Ultrabeat. Its very sad that they are missing because I really wanted to use them
The problem is also described here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7767382

I am using Logic Pro X Version **10.4.3**. Maybe one of you knows a solution. It also might be the case that apple removed those presets.

How it currently looks without presets
[image: How Ultrabeat looks like]

How it should look like with presets
[image: How it should look like]

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to download the presets. Look under Logic Pro X >> Sound Library >> Open sound library. Select various drum kits and download.

I run 10.4.3 as well and have a lot of presets available. (I have download all of the Sound Libraries which ends up beeing quite a few GB).

Comment: This worked for me. I downloaded the libraries which were about 18 GB and then clicked on import at the top of the Ultrabeat box to use the kits.